# How to resolve 401 Unauthorized in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, 401

I am working with SharePoint On premises environment.

I am facing a very strange issue while using the SharePoint site.

Whenever I open any URL it automatically insert following string the URL

```
_layouts/15/start.aspx#/
```

Example, when I open **Site Content**, the URL should be like

```
http://URL:PORT NUMBER/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx
```

But it always takes as

```
http://URL:PORT NUMBER/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx
```

And due to this I always get the following message

[image]

And when I remove the unwanted string then it works fine.

Any resolution to this or any reason why it always take the URL like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are noticing the URL with _layouts/15/start.aspx because the feature Minimal Download Strategy is activated on your site.

If you don't want _layouts/15/start.aspx to be a part of your URL you need to deactivate Minimal Download Strategy feature available under Site Actions -> Manager Site Features

information about this feature you can explore here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds

Comment: This was really helpful... thank you.